# Retrieving objects from Parse data browser

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I've successfully saved an object to the parse data browser and I'm able to see the object on the website, but I'm having a trouble retrieving this object in my android app
here is the code I'm using

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());  
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);                        
}
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    Parse.initialize(this, "App ID", "Client ID");  
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> q = ParseQuery.getQuery("TestObject");
    q.getInBackground("BRUlhLSW6d", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject arg0, ParseException arg1) {
            Log.d("test4", "good");
            if (arg1 != null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, arg0.getString("foo").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Help", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I see a more generic error there: you must call Parse.initialize() in the very beginning of your application, not every time an item is selected. Also ensure that App ID and Client ID are actually the correct keys of your Parse account.

Comment: @alessandro.francesconi still same problem my friend, the app is still not starting

Comment: App not starting? so what's the real problem here? Is the done() callback called after starting the query? (in other words... is Log.d("test4", "good") actually called)?

Comment: @alessandro.francesconi my app is stopping at parse initialization point (NoClassDefFound exception) , but im 100% sure that both keys are right.

Comment: You should have write this at the first line of the question ;)
Seems more a problem with the Parse library linking in your project...

Comment: @alessandro.francesconi I don't know I tried everything..anyway thanks a lot I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what you're expecting to do into the GetCallback, but... In the done() method you are (probably) checking for a "good result" when arg1 is NOT null. That is, instead, the error case (arg1 is the exception).

So, most probably your query works but you missed the if branch.

Comment: I'm just testing if i'm able to retrieve the object from the data browser. I've found that code in Parse.com documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I know what you're doing wrong; you have:

```
     if (arg1 != null) {
//this means there was an error fetching the object
...
```

instead of

```
    if (arg1 == null) {
//this means it succeeds
    ...
    }
```

Comment: If this does not solve your problem, please provide a logcat, and explain more; does your app crash or just simply doesn't open?